# Galaxy S3 Active Sync is not working, any help?

Tags: exchange, connection-issues, active-sync

I cant sync my business email on my Android mobile (a Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4).

I tried to set up a business email account but all I get is *unable to connect to server* after I'm done with the set up. I'm pretty sure server and configuration details are correct.

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft exchange 2010.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and downloaded Touchdown for Smartphones, which worked.  Will Send the phone back as clearly the bundled app that came with the phone isn't working but another program with the same settings worked.  Only bought the S3 a week ago, first phone the WIFI and the Bluetooth wouldn't switch on, 2nd phone no exchange e-mail, third time lucky?